# Redirigir IPV4 a dominio personalizado

Tags: mysql, windows, apache, xampp

Tengo un xampp montado, en un pc, en el que accedo a **localhost** mediante el dominio **test.domain.com**, modificando el archivo `host` añadiendo la siguiente linea:

```
127.0.0.1 test.domain.com
```

También he configurado el archivo `httpd-vhosts.conf` del xampp para añadir lo siguiente

```html
<virtualhost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
  ServerName test.domain.com
</virtualhost>
```

Y en mi pc funciona perfecto, pero quiero acceder a este localhost a través de un smartphone  vía web, en mi caso entro a traves de `192.168.1.39` y sin ningún problema tampoco

Mi pregunta es, hay alguna manera de acceder mediante el dominio **test.domain.com** en mi smartphone, debería de configurar algo en el host de mi pc, xampp o tiene que ser mediante la configuración del smartphone?

Comment: En ese caso tenes que acceder con la ip publica de tu dispositivo porque la que ingresas es una ip local, la resolvera solo si no posees conexion a internet

Comment: @CarlosLópez si está conectado a la LAN vía WiFi, el teléfono le va a resolver la IP privada sin problema.

Comment: @Pelukosa el teléfono estaría conectado por la red de datos o por WiFi?

Comment: En efecto @Pelukosa es como dice Alfabravo, la resuelve de manera local, acabo de realizar una prueba y para lo otro creo que seria con un servidor dns para que resuleva la ip a nombre de dominio pero solo funcionaria en red local, para hacerlo publico creo que ya debes comprar un nombre de dominio y registrarlo con tu ip

Comment: Sólo lo necesito en modo local conectado el smartphone a la misma red wifi

Comment: He probado entrando a test.domain.com desde mi smarthphone (conectado a via wifi) y me salta un DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Comment: Todo depende de las opciones de tu celular y cómo es la topología de tu red local. Opciones: (A) Si el celular está rooteado, cambiando el archivo `etc/hosts` en Android https://android.stackexchange.com/a/110483 (B) Si el router WiFi te lo permite, cambiando el servidor DNS a uno en tu server (C) Agregando un servidor DNS en tu celular https://devilbox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/dns/add-custom-dns-server-on-android.html (D) Olvidarte de `test.domain.com` y usar un dominio No-IP gratuito (público).

Comment: Si tienes el telefono en la misma red que el sever no te funcionara nunca por nombre de dominio. Yo tengo varios server (raspB) en casa y lo tengo mas que comprobado, unicamente entro con IP cuando estoy en casa y con la URL cuando estoy fuera o con datos.

Comment: ¿Qué sistema operativo tienes en tu servidor? La resolución de nombres locales no funcionan fuera de tu equipo, por lo que debes instalar un servidor DNS que realice esa resolución falsa y configurar en tu router de Internet que asigne como servidor DNS el de tu servidor. Aunque, como te han propuesto, es mucho más fácil usar un dominio gratuito (que te permita configurar entradas DNS) o bien un subdominio dinámico gratuito (como los que ofrece no-ip o cualquier otro proveedor similar). Otra opción es modificar el archivo hosts de tu móvil, pero para ello necesitas tener root en él.

Comment: si el router es compatible con [openwrt](https://openwrt.org/) podes actualizarle el firmware y usarlo como dns resolver para direcciones locales

Answer (score 1):

Para poder acceder con una dirección de dominio local, debes configurar un servidor DNS local dentro de tu Router, de forma que cuando al Router le llegue la petición de la url test.domain.com, la redirija a la dirección local de tu maquina `192.168.1.39`
Si me indicas el modelo de tu router puedo ayudarte con ello.
Con este método podrías acceder con ese dominio desde cualquier dispositivo de tu red local.